# Send NSDictionary as an parameter in @selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, selector, nsthread

How can I send my NSDictionary on my selector, as a parameter, and how I can read it?

```
NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"idOferta",@"test", nil];                
NSThread * viewsThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateViewStatistic:) object:dict];
[viewsThread start];

- (void)updateViewStatistic:(NSThread *)mt {
      NSLog(@"dictionary %@",dict); 
}
```

Comment: It seems that you didn't read the documentation, or at least you didn't read it carefully enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `updateViewStatistic:` method to something like this:

```
- (void)updateViewStatistic:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", dictionary);
}
```

Comment: The exact same answer is posted to the duplicate, as it has already been stated - no need for reproducing it.